# Add discounts in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I am working on prestashop 1.7. I have added some products to cart through php code using prestashops provided classes. In older prestashop versions there is a function called addDiscounts in the cart class that can be used to add the discounts to shopping cart. But in prestashop 1.7 it says cannot find this function in cart class. After going through the class I couldn't find it myself. Any idea what has replaced this function or was it added somewhere else?

Comment: Any good members who already gave me or are going to give me -ve points please tell me what would be the reason for this as I might have not understood the purpose of this website since I think here programmers share their problems or things they don't know or understand. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. The function addDiscount has been renamed to addcartrule with the argument as the cartrule id. Cheers.